# Crear index automáticamente al crear una relación foranea

Tags: mysql

Verán, estoy creando unas cuantas bases de datos en PHPMyAdmin, pero me estoy encontrando con un serio obstáculo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada vez que quiero crear una clave foránea estoy obligado a crear antes en la columna foránea un índice, por lo que me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que pase esto a ser automático.

Comment: Eh, una llave foránea referencia una llave primaria de otra tabla. Claro que debe estar indexada porque la PK crea un índice asociado. "Es automático" porque has debido crear la PK pa declarar la FK :)

Comment: Como la estas intentando crear, por la consola de MySQL o por PHPmyadmin

Comment: @MateoGuio Directamente por PHPmyadmin.

Comment: No, la herramienta no puede adivinar o inferir todas la opciones posibles de un índice: `UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL`, `BTREE|HASH`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta consulta, debes darle al apartado que dice SQL y pones esto:

```
ALTER TABLE edicion ADD FOREIGN KEY (horario) REFERENCES horario (codigo);
```

Te recomiendo que dejes un id unico para cada tabla, y dirijas la llave foranea a ese id. En ese caso seria primero

```
ALTER TABLE edicion ADD id int(11) auto_increment primary key;
```

Luego lo mismo con la tabla horario

```
ALTER TABLE horario ADD id int(11) auto_increment primary key;
```

Luego si apunta las llaves foraneas a esos ids.

```
ALTER TABLE edicion ADD FOREIGN KEY (horario) REFERENCES horario (id);
```

Comment: Esto no es lo que busco. Lo que quiero es que si estoy en el diseñador e indico que una columna de una tabla es clave foránea de la clave primaria de otra, automáticamente se cree el índice para que no necesite hacer eso manualmente.